# change body colour back to white if not hover on div

Tags: jquery, css

I have this script which changes body background when hover on particular div. I want to change the body colour back to original colour if mouse is on body but after 2s.

```js
$( "#attacker" ).hover(function() {
  $('body').css({"background":"url(img/4178903.jpg)",'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-size':'cover','background-attachment' : 'fixed','background-position':'center','transition': 'background-image 0.8s ease-in-out'});
});

$( "#midfield" ).hover(function() {
    $('body').css({"background-image":"url(img/david-villa-football-players-hd-wallpaper-876271979.jpg)",'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-size':'cover','background-attachment' : 'fixed','background-position':'center','transition': 'background-image 0.8s ease-in-out'});
});
            $( "#defender" ).hover(function() {
   $('body').css({"background":"url(img/Cristiano_Ronaldo_and_Gennaro_Gattuso_Football_Player_Wallpaper.jpg)",'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-size':'cover','background-attachment' : 'fixed','background-position':'center','transition': 'background-image 0.8s ease-in-out'});
                });
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
 background: #fbc73b;
 font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto 100px auto;
 max-width: 960px;
}

.stage {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
}

/*************************************
Build the scene and rotate on hover
**************************************/

.scene {
 width: 260px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 30px;
 float: left;
 -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
 -moz-perspective: 1000px;
 perspective: 1000px;
}

.movie {
 width: 260px;
 height: 400px;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(-130px);
 -moz-transform: translateZ(-130px);
 transform: translateZ(-130px);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 350ms;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 350ms;
 transition: transform 350ms;
}

.movie:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(-78deg) translateZ(20px);
 -moz-transform: rotateY(-78deg) translateZ(20px);
 transform: rotateY(-78deg) translateZ(20px);
}

/*************************************
Transform and style the two planes
**************************************/

.movie .poster, 
.movie .info {
 position: absolute;
 width: 260px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: #fff;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.movie .poster  {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(130px);
 -moz-transform: translateZ(130px);
 transform: translateZ(130px);
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.movie .info {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(130px);
 -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(130px);
 transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(130px);
 border: 1px solid #B8B5B5;
 font-size: 0.75em;
}

/*************************************
Shadow beneath the 3D object
**************************************/

.csstransforms3d .movie::after {
 content: '';
 width: 260px;
 height: 260px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 box-shadow: 0 30px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(130px);
 -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(130px);
 transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(130px);
 -webkit-transition: box-shadow 350ms;
 -moz-transition: box-shadow 350ms;
 transition: box-shadow 350ms;
}

.csstransforms3d .movie:hover::after {
 box-shadow: 20px -5px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

/*************************************
Movie information
**************************************/

.info header {
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 7px 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 195px;
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.info header h1 {
 margin: 0 0 2px;
 font-size: 1.4em;
}

.info header .rating {
 border: 1px solid #FFF;
 padding: 0px 3px;
}

.info p {
 padding: 1.2em 1.4em;
 margin: 2px 0 0;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #666;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 border-top: 10px solid #555;
}

/*************************************
Generate "lighting" using box shadows
**************************************/

.movie .poster,
.movie .info,
.movie .info header {
 -webkit-transition: box-shadow 350ms;
 -moz-transition: box-shadow 350ms;
 transition: box-shadow 350ms;
}

.csstransforms3d .movie .poster {
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 40px rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

.csstransforms3d .movie:hover .poster {
 box-shadow: inset 300px 0px 40px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.csstransforms3d .movie .info, 
.csstransforms3d .movie .info header {
 box-shadow: inset -300px 0px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.csstransforms3d .movie:hover .info, 
.csstransforms3d .movie:hover .info header {
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

/*************************************
Posters and still images
**************************************/

.scene:nth-child(1) .movie .poster {
  background-image: url(../img/poster01.jpg);
}

.scene:nth-child(2) .poster {
  background-image: url(../img/poster02.jpg);
}

.scene:nth-child(3) .poster {
  background-image: url(../img/poster03.jpg);
}

.scene:nth-child(1) .info header {
 background-image: url(../img/still01.jpg);
}

.scene:nth-child(2) .info header {
 background-image: url(../img/still02.jpg);
}

.scene:nth-child(3) .info header {
 background-image: url(../img/still03.jpg);
}

/*************************************
Fallback
**************************************/
.no-csstransforms3d .movie .poster, 
.no-csstransforms3d .movie .info {
 position: relative;
}

/*************************************
Media Queries
**************************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 60.75em){
 .scene {
  float: none;
  margin: 30px auto 60px;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" >
       
   
   <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="stage clearfix" >

     <li class="scene">
      <div class="movie i1" onclick="return true" id="attacker">
       <div class="poster"></div>
       <div class="info">
        <header>
         <h1>THE ATTACKER</h1>
         <span class="year">1946</span>
         <span class="rating">GAME TIME</span>
         <span class="duration">90 minutes</span>
        </header>
        <p>
         In Bedford Falls, New York on Christmas Eve, George Bailey is deeply troubled. Prayers for his well-being from friends and family reach Heaven. Clarence Odbody, Angel Second Class, is assigned to visit Earth to save George, thereby earning his wings. Franklin and Joseph, the head angels, review George's life with Clarence.
        </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>

     <li class="scene">
      <div class="movie i2" onclick="return true" id="midfield">
       <div class="poster"></div>
       <div class="info">
        <header>
         <h1>THE MID-FIELDER</h1>
         <span class="year">1951</span>
         <span class="rating">GAME TIME</span>
         <span class="duration">90 minutes</span>
        </header>
        <p>
         A cattle baron takes in an orphaned boy and raises him, causing his own son to resent the boy. As they get older the resentment festers into hatred, and eventually the real son frames his stepbrother for fathering an illegitimate child that is actually his, seeing it as an opportunity to get his half-brother out of the way so he can have his father's empire all to himself.
        </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>

     <li class="scene">
      <div class="movie i3" onclick="return true" id="defender">
       <div class="poster"></div>
       <div class="info">
        <header>
         <h1>The DEFENFER</h1>
         <span class="year">1925</span>
         <span class="rating">GAME TIME</span>
         <span class="duration">90 minutes</span>
        </header>
        <p>
         The Tramp travels to the Yukon to take part in the Klondike Gold Rush. He gets mixed up with some burly characters and falls in love with the beautiful Georgia. He tries to win her heart with his singular charm.
        </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
                    <li class="scene">
      <div class="movie i4" onclick="return true" id="goalkeeper">
       <div class="poster"></div>
       <div class="info">
        <header>
         <h1>The GOALKEEPER</h1>
         <span class="year">1925</span>
         <span class="rating">GAME TIME</span>
         <span class="duration">90 minutes</span>
        </header>
        <p>
         The Tramp travels to the Yukon to take part in the Klondike Gold Rush. He gets mixed up with some burly characters and falls in love with the beautiful Georgia. He tries to win her heart with his singular charm.
        </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>

    </ul>
   </div><!-- /wrapper -->
  </div><!-- /container -->
```

I tried giving body a id but that doesn't work because div on hover has a after property which flips it so very less tie is there to change the background and therefore this technique failed

Comment: Post your HTML here for simplicity.

Comment: Kindly post your HTML and FORMAT your JS for EASY READING :)

Comment: Added html js and css @AKA

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div').addClass('body');

$('div').on('mouseenter',function(){
  $('div').addClass('hover');
  $('div').removeClass('body');
});


$('div').on('mouseleave',function(){
  $('div').addClass('body');
  $('div').removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
.body{
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
}

.hover{
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">Body</div>
```

just like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mydiv").hover(
    function() {
        //mouse over
        $('body').css('background', '#000000');
    }, function() {
        //mouse out
       $('body').css('background', '#ffffff');
    });
});
```

```css
.mydiv{
    background:#f0f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="mydiv">test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its not happening with ease the transition is too fast